# Outputting value of a For-Loop on last iteration only

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, sequence

I am trying to output the value of `i` for the loop `index(i)`, but only on the last iteration. I either get an error or it outputs all values of `i`. Here is what I have so far:

```
boolean sequentialSearch(int x) {

       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  //n comes from function length()

           if(n != 0) {

               if(list[i] == x) {

                   return true;
               }

               return false;
           }
}
```

Comment: your code has several issues, could you explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if(list[i] == x) { // an array is 0-indexed
        System.out.println("Found at index: " + i);
        return true;   // return true if found
    }
}
System.out.println("Not found!");
return false;      // here, x has never been found, so return false
```

Comment: I want to output i as well, so far yours does exactly what mine does above

Comment: I edited my answer. If you want your code to return the index, return ``i`` instead of ``true`` and ``-1`` instead of ``false``.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need sth like this:

```
boolean sequentialSearch(int x) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { //n comes from function length()
        if(list[i]==x){   // list comes from somewhere too
            System.out.println(i); // print i
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need to print the last `i` possible start from the tail of array:

```
boolean sequentialSearch(int x) {
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) { //n comes from function length()
        if(list[i]==x){   // list comes from somewhere too
            System.out.println(i); // print i
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Great, I definatly had a duh moment. LOL.  Thanks!  I was thinking it was more complex than that.

Comment: Happy to help! I would really appreciate you accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Why u check i!=0,
instead of iterate from `i=1;`

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
 {
    if(list[i] == x) 
    { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

This much easier. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to print `i` and return a boolean?  Since `-1` is often used for *not found*, why not split this into two methods. Now you can search for whatever purpose you want, even if it's a system where `System.out` is unavailable as in a web application.

```
boolean sequentialSearch(int x) {
    for(int i = 0, n = list.length; i < n; i++) { 
        if(list[i] == x) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Later
int index = sequentialSearch(y);
if (index != -1) {
    System.out.println(y + " found at index " + index);
} else {
    System.out.println(y + " not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how to print the last value alone?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the value of n: ");
        int n = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {   
            n3 = n1 + n2;

            n1 = n2;
            n2 = n3;
        System.out.println(""+n3);
        }
    }
}
```